# Multiple Fragments in each page of a BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-framelayout

I use a **BottomNavigationView** with four pages. If I want to add 4 fragments to that it is Ok but when I want to replace new fragment with old fragment in one of the **BottomNavigationView** page and restore it when item click, the first fragment open again. How can I restore the last fragment? Should I use different **FrameLayout** in the first **BottomNavigationView**?

Comment: No. Use fragment as child of main fragment. Read more about child fragment manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bottomNavView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(object : BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

                clearAllBackStack()
                when (item.itemId) {
                    R.id.itemHome -> {
                      // load fragment here
                    }

                    R.id.itemMyAccount -> {
                      // load fragment here
                    }

                    R.id.itemSettings -> {
                       // load fragment here
                    }

                    R.id.itemNotfications -> {
                        // load fragment here
                    }
                }
                return true
            }
        })
```

add this method:

```
 fun clearAllBackStack() {
        for (i in 0 until supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount) {
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        }
    }
```

**Note:** also add fragment to backstack whenever you load fragment, add this when you load fragment: `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)`

Comment: So how can I show fragment from last state when I changed item in BottomNavigationView clicked?

Comment: I did not understand what kind of flow you want?

Comment: For example in first item of BottomNavigatioView I have a fragment that shows a list in it. If I clicked on each item of this list, a new fragment opened to show details of that list's item. Then I changed to anther item of BottomNavigationView and again came back to first item of BottomNavigationView. Now I want to see the details fragment not list fragment.

Comment: add this fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)

 for every fragment you are starting, and let me know what happens

Comment: @behrooz.fard have you found a solution? What Suraj is saying looks like wrong